# Sass calculcate columnwidth percentage

Tags: css, sass, css-transitions, compass-sass

I'm trying to make my own little columngrid with sass but I can't wrap my head around this problem.

This is what I have come up with so far but it is no the right solution. I'm getting a clean grid like this but the problem is that I'm removing an extra percentage in every row.

I'm removing the gutter_width of 1%(in this case) on the width of each column and replacing the room by using my gutter_width as the margin-left. So for each column I'm removing a percentage and adding it as margin, creating the gutters. The problem arises when I remove margin of the first-child in the row wich leaves me with a 99% row.

Could somebody help me out with this? Or maybe suggest a better way.

```
$container_width: 970px; // Main container width
$gutter_width: 1%;
$columns: 12; // Twelve columns


/*  #Calculate the columnwidths  */
/*  Calculate the width of a single column and multiple it by columncount
================================================== */

@for $i from 1 through $columns {
    .column-#{$i} {
        width: ((100% / $columns) * $i) - $gutter_width;
    }
}

.container {
    max-width: $container_width;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1em 0;
    @include pie-clearfix;
}

// Select all element that contains class 'column'
[class*="column"] {
    float: left;
    margin-left: $gutter_width;
    &:first-child {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be one less gutter than there are columns - both in the context and in the span-width. The correct math is actually:

```
// the width of a single column has to account for "$columns - 1" gutters.
$column_width: (100% - $gutter_width * ($columns - 1)) / $columns;

@for $i from 1 through $columns {
  .column-#{$i} {
    the width of a span should cover "$i" columns, plus "$i - 1" gutters
    width: $column-width * $i + $gutter_width * ($i -1);
  }
}
```

Classes like this create a fairly fragile system if you want to nest any grid-spans inside other grid-spans, but it should cover the basics. Once you are using a pre-processor like Sass, I recommend leaving behind `.column-x` classes entirely, and just using mixins.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have removed a $gutter_width from the first child you need to add it again to the last. One way to go about it could be to place this inside your loops:

```
&:last-of-type{
   width: (100% / $columns) * $i;
}
```

That way if the column is the last element the width is recalculated with the extra 1%. If you want older browser support just replace it with a utility class called .last-column or something.